# Jenkins cannot use docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, cloudbees

I've installed jenkins in my k8s cluster through helm.
Ive been trying to build the docker image and push it to gitlab registery so i can use it for deployment later though cloudbees docker plugin but i kept getting this error this error:

```
   Started by user admin
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Build
using credential gitlab
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://gitlab.com/Ferios08/letsdevops-angular.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://gitlab.com/Ferios08/letsdevops-angular.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials gitlab
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://gitlab.com/Ferios08/letsdevops-angular.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision bbfedaeb976edde010c496c63de43ec01184011e (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f bbfedaeb976edde010c496c63de43ec01184011e # timeout=10
Commit message: "fixed deploy"
 > git rev-list --no-walk bbfedaeb976edde010c496c63de43ec01184011e # timeout=10
[Build] $ /var/jenkins_home/tools/org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.commons.tools.DockerTool/docker/bin/docker build -t registry.gitlab.com/ferios08/letsdevops-angular --pull=true /var/jenkins_home/workspace/Build
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

any ideas how to fix it? and thanks

Comment: try running with `sudo`

Comment: You failed to state whether your helm chart contains a `volume: hostPath:` that exposes the host's `/var/run/docker.sock` to your Pod; you actually failed to specify **anything** about your install, as if we are psychic

Comment: Please provide steps that you did to get to this stage.

Comment: sorry for the late reply:
I've installed Jenkins in k8s cluster using helm through this [link](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/jenkins)
the problem that jenkins doesn't have the permission to use docker and i kinda cannot change that the fact i it's not installed on a separated machine.
when i install Jenkins separately it works when i use `sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins`

Comment: How was your Kubernetes cluster created? Bare metal, GKE, AKS, EKS?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me your docker daemon is not running.

Comment: @Jakub I can't use sudo with jenkins on k8s

Comment: it's more about permission

Comment: how so ? It's clear your service is not running or does not any file opened for IPC usage or for determining if it's running (i.e. sock/run)

Comment: it works normally when installing Jenkins outside of the cluster and typing `sudo usermod -aG docker jenkins` to give it permission to use docker.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to docker daemon **inside** the container, but docker daemon inside your container is not running.

There are several possibilities:

1. You can run [docker in docker](https://www.docker.com/blog/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/)
2. You can bind the docker socket of your cluster to your container with -v

`docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`

3. You can connect docker inside your container to some remote docker socket using [docker context](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/context/) (with docker version >=19.03)
4. You can just install jenkins outside of the cluster